# Is there an asynchronous job when setting permissions programmatically?

Tags: 2007, permissions

This is in Sharepoint 2007.

Suddenly, we've notice that our web service which sets permissions on items in a document library don't show the new permissions immediately. After a minimum of 30 mins, the items correctly show the custom permissions.

This was working about a month ago.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one SP server in the farm?  Sometimes they can get out of sync.  Maybe try rebooting them all and see if that helps.  I have also seen before where clearing out a file cache on them helps as well.  If restarting doesn't fix it, let me know and I'll try to remember what files need to be deleted.